# Get weighted average between 2 columns only for cells with matching indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
df_idx = ['P{}'.format(i) for i in range(7)] + ['Y0']
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 4,5],
    'B': [np.nan, 2, np.nan ,4,6,8, np.nan ,10],
    'C': [1,3,5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,7,9]
}, index=df_idx)

    A   B   C
P0  1       1
P1  2   2   3
P2          5
P3  3   4   
P4      6   
P5      8   
P6  4       7
Y0  5   10  9
```

And this series

```
ser_idx = ['P{}'.format(i) for i in range(8) ] + ['X{}'.format(i) for i in range(3)]
series = pd.Series([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.1,1.2], index = ser_idx)
    factors
P0  0.1
P1  0.2
P2  0.3
P3  0.4
P4  0.5
P5  0.6
P6  0.7
P7  0.8
X0  0.9
X1  1.1
X2  1.2
```

Now I want to get the weighted mean for each column of `df` with `series`, obviously only for the cells that match the index. For instance column `A` has P1 value = 2 and series has P1=0.2, I want the result to have P1=(a* 2+ b* 0.2)/(a+b), where a and b are the weight I arbitrarily assign each time I perform the average.
Note that `series` and `df` may have different indexes, the resulting column should contain both unique indexes from those objects. NaNs should be considered as 0, so `fillna()` can be used at the start of the process.
I will manually write what the first column should look like in the case a=b (arithmetic mean)

```
    A
P0  0.55
P1  1.1
P2  
P3  1.7
P4  
P5  
P6  2.35
Y0  2.5
P7  
X0  
X1  
X2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this.

The easiest way I could think of was to merge the dataframe and series into a new dataframe, then change the values of this dataframe and finally drop the series column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_idx = ['P{}'.format(i) for i in range(7)] + ['Y0']
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 4,5],
    'B': [np.nan, 2, np.nan ,4,6,8, np.nan ,10],
    'C': [1,3,5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,7,9]
}, index=df_idx)

ser_idx = ['P{}'.format(i) for i in range(8) ] + ['X{}'.format(i) for i in range(3)]
series = pd.Series([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.1,1.2], index = ser_idx)

a = 1
b = 1

df2 = df.merge(series.to_frame().rename(columns={0: "series"}),
               left_index=True, right_index=True,
               how="outer").fillna(0)

for i in df.columns:
    df2[i] = (((df2[i] * a) + (df2["series"] * b)) / (a + b))

df2.drop(columns=["series"], inplace=True)
```

My output is:

```
#Out: 
#       A     B     C
#P0  0.55  0.05  0.55
#P1  1.10  1.10  1.60
#P2  0.15  0.15  2.65
#P3  1.70  2.20  0.20
#P4  0.25  3.25  0.25
#P5  0.30  4.30  0.30
#P6  2.35  0.35  3.85
#P7  0.40  0.40  0.40
#X0  0.45  0.45  0.45
#X1  0.55  0.55  0.55
#X2  0.60  0.60  0.60
#Y0  2.50  5.00  4.50
```

This output will be different depending on where you put the `.fillna()`.  Because I merged the dataframe first, then set all `Nan` values to 0, my column A is slightly different.  You might have to move it around until you get to the exact output you want.